# How to fix .offset error when upgrading from jQuery 1.3.2 -> 1.4.2

Tags: offset, jquery-1.4

I just upgraded jQuery to version 1.4.2 and I am now getting an error on this line

```
var offset = $(settings.textBoxObj).offset({padding: true, border: true});
```

Before I upgraded I was not getting this error. Does anyone know if something changed in 1.4 to affect this line of code?

Metropolis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line is completely wrong.

In jQuery 1.3.*x*, `offset` didn't take any parameters, so your object was ignored.

In 1.4, `offset` allows you to move an element, so it expects an object with `left` and `top` properties.

You need to figure out what the parameter was trying to accomplish or remove it completely.

Comment: Thanks SLaks. I looked at it a little more and I realized I was trying to get the offset object so that I could do offset.left, and offset.right. I removed the parameters and it works now. Im not really sure where I got those parameters from :p